# How to change format from seconds to hh:mm:ss?

Tags: r

I need to transform a seconds to hh:mm:ss format in R.
I use the `difftime()` function to have the difference between two dates and I specify `units="mins"`.

But for the final result, I want it as `hh:mm:ss` and not only by specifying hour, or minutes, o seconds.

Comment: Just use `lubridate::as.period` on the results you obtain after using the `difftime` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using lubridate.

```
library(lubridate)
seconds_to_period(86400)
#[1] "1d 0H 0M 0S"

seconds_to_period(48000)
#[1] "13H 20M 0S"
```

Then format the date:

```
td <- seconds_to_period(86400)
sprintf('%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', day(td), td@hour, minute(td), second(td))
#[1] "01 00:00:00"
```

Comment: Yes il already use the lubridate library. Thank you very much, it works with the function seconds to period.

Answer (score 1):

Try using hms package:

```
library(hms)    
hms::as_hms(99)
#[1] 00:01:39
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `%/%` and `%%` operators

```
t = 99
sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", t %/% 3600, (t %% 3600) %/% 60, t %% 60)
#[1] "00:01:39"
```